# Telegram bot, is it possible to be sure that the image was not picked from the gallery

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

**Is it possible to detect some information about an image sent to a Telegram bot?**

- the source of the image is the camera or the gallery.
- the time image was created. (not message sending time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When receiving a photo, the Telegram Bot API sends back only width, height, file size and a photo id to download the photo according to its [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#photosize). Therefore:

- The source of the photo can not be determined by the API itself unless this information can be found somewhere in the metadata of the photo itself. However, I believe that this would probably only show you the type of device the user was using, not the app the photo was taken with.
- It is more likely, that you can find metadata about when the image was created in the image itself. In order to get to that data, you would have to download the photo and then use another tool to extract the metadata from the photo.

I have worked a lot with Telegram Bots and can confirm that Telegram does not transmit a lot of information about the user, the device the user is using, where files are coming from etc. in the API itself, which is actually in favour of its users.

Comment: The chances are higher if the photo is sent as document, i.e. the original file is sent. If it's send as photo, Telegram compresses the photo, which likely drops most of the metadata.